# jquery perform a different action every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to perform a different action every 60 seconds to change my background via animate.
Now run by clicking.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("li.one").click( function(){ 
    $('#switch-container').animate({backgroundColor: '#18597f'}, 1000)
});

$("li.two").click( function(){ 
    $('#switch-container').animate({backgroundColor: '#8a0651'}, 1000)
});

$("li.three").click( function(){ 
    $('#switch-container').animate({backgroundColor: '#8a0651'}, 1000)
});
```

how could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var colors = ['#18597f','#8a0651','#8a0651'],
    timer  = setInterval(function() {
        var rand = parseInt(Math.random()*(3 - 0),10);
        $('#switch-container').animate({backgroundColor: colors[rand]}, 1000);
    }, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssPku/4/)

EDIT:

to change colors in a regular order and not randomly:

```
var colors = ['green','red','yellow'],
    i      = 0,
    timer  = setInterval(function() {
        $('#switch-container').animate({backgroundColor: colors[i++]}, 500);
        i = i==3 ? 0 : i;
    }, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssPku/5/)

Comment: if I want no random colors but 1,2,3,1,2,3 how can i do? Thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi - added that to the answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval()`.

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals **(in milliseconds)**.

```
setInterval(function(){
  //code for animation
},DURATION);
```

Comment: @Manoz yes i have added from there just to make OP clear about what this function is for...sorry if giving explanation to OP is my fault then sorry...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //  alert("hello");
        changecolor();
    });
    function changecolor() {
        // alert("hi");
        var colors = ["#00FF00", "#CCCCCC", "#990099", "#FEA400", "#FF9900", "#6600FF", "#333333", ];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        $('#controls-wrapper').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
        setTimeout('changecolor()', 100);
    }
```

If you don't care if the code within the timer may take longer than your interval, use setInterval():

```
setInterval(function, delay)
```

That fires the function passed in as first parameter over and over.

A better approach is, to use setTimeout along with a self-executing anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    // do some stuff
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

that guarantees, that the next call is not made before your code was executed. I used arguments.callee in this example as function reference. It's a better way to give the function a name and call that within setTimeout because arguments.callee is deprecated in ecmascript 5.

Answer (score 0):

I used this template once: http://luiszuno.com/themes/kroft/
It has an animated background. Check the html files for the html, the slider.js file for your variable time and the slides folder for the backend jquery code